# Can tree be used to list the number of files per level?

Tags: directory, directory-structure, tree

I need to look into a particular directory and list the number of files per level. The directory is pretty large, about 10-15 levels deep. For instance, if I have the following:

```
D1
|
|-- D2A (5 files in this directory)
|    |-- D3A (6 files in this directory)
|    |-- D3B (7 Files in this directory)
|
|-- D2B (1 file in this directory)
```

Then it should tell me that level 3 has 13 files and level 2 has 6 files (or 6+13, doesn't matter). Can `Tree` accomplish this? I've tried around mixing the options but it does not seem to work.

Comment: `tree` can't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type d | \
perl -ne 'BEGIN{ sub cnt{ $file=shift; $c="find $file -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l";int(`$c`) }} chomp; printf "%s %s\n", $_, cnt($_)' | \
perl -ne '/^(.*) (\d*)$/; $_{scalar(split /\//, $1)}+=$2; END { printf "Depth %d has %d files.\n", @$_ for map { [$_,$_{$_}] } sort keys %_ }'
```

Results:

```
Depth 1 has 7 files.
Depth 2 has 2353 files.
Depth 3 has 2558 files.
Depth 4 has 8242 files.
Depth 5 has 6452 files.
Depth 6 has 674 files.
Depth 7 has 1112 files.
Depth 8 has 64 files.
Depth 9 has 154 files.
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if `tree` can accomplish this.  However, `find` can:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f | wc -l
```

would return the number of files at level 3.

Answer (score 2):

```
tree | sed 's/ //g;s/`/\|/g;s/-.*//g' | sort | uniq -c | grep \|
```

Results:

```
     35 |
    186 ||
   1408 |||
    691 ||||
```

The pipe (|) character indicates the depth.